# Space invaders game

Tags: java, collections

I am writing a space invaders game I need to write 5 public instance variables which hold collections recording all of the information about one run of the game:

spaceShips will reference a list of SpaceShip, in the order they appeared on the screen

> public List spaceShips;

blinks are shots which will reference a list of all instances of Blink in the order which they occured

> public List blinks;

hitsMap which will reference a map, who keys will be instances of Spaceship that where hit by a blink and whose values will be lists corresponding 'successful' instances of blink

> ????

unscathed which will reference a list of all instances of SpaceShip that were not 'hit' by any blink

> ???

misses, which will reference a list of all instances of Blink that did not 'hit' any spaceship

> ???

I then have to add lines to the constructor to assign a new instance of HashMap to hits map and ArrayList to the other variables, so far i have

> spaceShips = new ArrayList();
>   blinks = new ArrayList();

Any help would be great

cheers

Comment: You told us what you have to do but what is the question?

Comment: I don't think you will need to keep references to shots. Make them event-based and let the garbage collector take them once they hit or missed.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 5 and up, you can use Generics to make your life *slightly* more simple. Use these definitions:

```
public List<SpaceShip> spaceShips = new ArrayList<SpaceShip>();
public List<Blink> blinks ...;
public Map<SpaceShip, List<Blink>> hitsMap = new HashMap<SpaceShip, List<Blink>>();
public List<SpaceShip> unscathed ...;
public List<Blink> misses ...;
```

To add a hit, use this code:

```
public void addHit(SpaceShip ship, Blink blink) {
    List<Blink> hits = hitsMap.get(spaceShip);
    if(null == hits) {
        hits = new ArrayList<Blank>();
        hitsMap.put(spaceShip, hits);
    }
    hits.add(blink);
}
```

That said, I suggest a slightly different API: Add a list of "hits" to `SpaceShip` and a boolean field `hit` (or maybe a reference to the space ship it did hit) to `Blink`. That way, relevant information will be in the affected object instance and you can use a simple filter on the list of `spaceShips` or `blinks` to get the other three lists/maps.

And mind your naming. Shouldn't "Blink" be "Missile" or "Shot"?

Comment: It smells like homework so I'm guessing he doesn't have a choice with regards to the API or data structures.

Comment: Maybe nice to mention that the Map<SpaceShip, List<Blink>> will only 'work properly' if you have overridden hashCode and equals in the SpaceShip class

Answer (score 0):

Some general points because this homework (at least, I think so - feel free to clarify if this is not the case).

1. Use generics in your data structures where possible. E.g. `List<SpaceShip> spaceShips`
2. Don't declare variables `public` by default (although having said that, I haven't seen the rest of you code so maybe there's a good reason why you've done that)

You've said that your `hitsMap` variable should be an instance of [`Map`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) but later on you've said that it needs to be a `HashMap`. Therefore there's not much choice but to declare `Map<SpaceShip, List<Blink>> hitsMap = new HashMap<SpaceShip, List<Blink>>();`

For your `misses` list, start by copying your list of all spaceships (maybe via [Collections.copy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) ?). As each `SpaceShip` gets hit, remove it from the `misses` list.

Your `misses` list should just be a `List<Blink>` that gets `Blink` objects added to it whenever you determine whether the `Blink` in question misses or hits (in which case you have to edit the `hitsMap`.

Answer (score 0):

You should also remember that you can use inheritance, and in this way define groups of classes that will have the same behavior, or interactions with other objects.

When Designing an object oriented game, you should always keep in mind that some graphic representations will move, others won't, some will destroy others, some will go through others, some won't. (probably with different priorities).

Also, I take the example of a PacMan game (what else :p) you have to remember some game entities can have states (like Pacman godmode, or Pacman vulnerable, opposite for Ghosts). Thus the idea of making Ghosts and Pacman (which are move/state related) children of a common abstract class.

Hope this helps !